# How to hold c++ console application active?

Tags: c++, console, rfid, always-on-top

I tried to hold my c++ program on top with `HWND_TOPMOST`. This code works and hold my application everytime on top, but not active. How can I hold the window everytime in focus and active? I want to write hex numbers with a RFID reader in my program, but on the same pc should do some other work. Maybe some c++ code were very helpful!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you really be able to do some other work on this PC while that form is always focused? Looks very strange.

Comment: I had some success with 'SetForegroundWindow' in a loop. Yes it is strange, everytime were the window active! Now, how can I get the Data from the RFID Reader in the background into my program? The reader write the hex Numerus in the actually active window. It is a EM4305. Is there a way to get the number from the USB HID device?